# Google Cloud Run and system capabilities

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a docker image which I am running on Google's Cloud Run.
When I want to run the image locally, I have to give my container additional capabilities like the following:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN gcr.io/my-project/my-docker-image
```

Is there a way of configuring [Docker's capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) in Cloud Run?

I stumbled upon this piece of [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/RevisionSpec#capabilities) from Google, but I don't know how to configure my container. I am not even sure that it is relevant to my situation.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the POSIX capabilities is not an option on Cloud Run or Cloud Run on GKE as they represent expanding the security vulnerabilities of the underlying host.

Adding capabilities is often the easiest way to make something with special system demands work. More complex but frequently doable are modifications within the container environment or to the package configuration to get things working.

If what you're trying to do absolutely requires cap-add, this might be addressed in a feature request to the software package... or it may be a novel use case that Cloud Run cannot support but may in the future with your feedback.

Comment: Do you know if I have access to this capability if I am supplying a Kubernetes cluster that my Cloud Run runs on?

Comment: What you're referring to (Cloud Run on GKE) is using Knative under the covers. Currently Knative doesn't allow you to set securityContext to the Kubernetes Pod spec so it's currently not possible.

Comment: Using puppeteer requires cap-add like this, does that mean you can't use puppeteer on google cloud? https://pptr.dev/guides/docker